# C ipc custom message how to?

Tags: c, ipc

I have the following code. How I can modify the following `msgtool` program so it can send another type of messages, not only strings?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/msg.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_SEND_SIZE 80

struct mymsgbuf {
    long mtype;
    char mtext[MAX_SEND_SIZE];
};

void send_message(int qid, struct mymsgbuf *qbuf, long type, char *text);
void read_message(int qid, struct mymsgbuf *qbuf, long type);
void remove_queue(int qid);
void change_queue_mode(int qid, char *mode);
void usage(void);


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    key_t key;
    int   msgqueue_id;
    struct mymsgbuf qbuf;

    if(argc == 1)
        usage();

    /* Create unique key via call to ftok() */
    key = ftok(".", 'm');

    /* Open the queue - create if necessary */
    if((msgqueue_id = msgget(key, IPC_CREAT|0660)) == -1) {
        perror("msgget");
        exit(1);
    }

    switch(tolower(argv[1][0]))
    {
        case 's': send_message(msgqueue_id, (struct mymsgbuf *)&qbuf,
                       atol(argv[2]), argv[3]); 
              break;
        case 'r': read_message(msgqueue_id, &qbuf, atol(argv[2])); 
              break;
        case 'd': remove_queue(msgqueue_id); 
              break;    
        case 'm': change_queue_mode(msgqueue_id, argv[2]); 
              break;

         default: usage();

    }

    return(0);
}

void send_message(int qid, struct mymsgbuf *qbuf, long type, char *text)
{
    /* Send a message to the queue */
    printf("Sending a message ...\n");
    qbuf->mtype = type;
    strcpy(qbuf->mtext, text);

    if((msgsnd(qid, (struct msgbuf *)qbuf,
        strlen(qbuf->mtext)+1, 0)) ==-1)
    {
        perror("msgsnd");
        exit(1);
    }
}

void read_message(int qid, struct mymsgbuf *qbuf, long type)
{
    /* Read a message from the queue */
    printf("Reading a message ...\n");
    qbuf->mtype = type;
    msgrcv(qid, (struct msgbuf *)qbuf, MAX_SEND_SIZE, type, 0);

    printf("Type: %ld Text: %s\n", qbuf->mtype, qbuf->mtext);
}

void remove_queue(int qid)
{
    /* Remove the queue */
    msgctl(qid, IPC_RMID, 0);
}

void change_queue_mode(int qid, char *mode)
{
    struct msqid_ds myqueue_ds;

    /* Get current info */
    msgctl(qid, IPC_STAT, &myqueue_ds);

    /* Convert and load the mode */
    sscanf(mode, "%ho", &myqueue_ds.msg_perm.mode);

    /* Update the mode */
    msgctl(qid, IPC_SET, &myqueue_ds);
}

void usage(void)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "msgtool - A utility for tinkering with msg queues\n");
    fprintf(stderr, "\nUSAGE: msgtool (s)end <type> <messagetext>\n");
    fprintf(stderr, "               (r)ecv <type>\n");
    fprintf(stderr, "               (d)elete\n");
    fprintf(stderr, "               (m)ode <octal mode>\n");
    exit(1);
}
```

Comment: The struct of msgbuf (mymsgbuf in your code) of message queue(system V IPC). must be formated (have the shape) that u have declared (struct mymsgbuf). its a matter of convention between sender and reciever. you can put in the char buffer what ever data you want! As long as the reciever understands and knows how to decode what you have sent

Comment: Give `mymsgbuf` any structure you want, except the mandatory heading long.